# How to run TestParallel.java when specifying test subset

Tags: karate

I have a TestParallel java class implemented as shown in DemoTestParallel.java to run parallel and run cucumber reports. Is there a way to run this class when executing a test subset (specifying the runner class or tags in the Maven command line arguments)? I'm hoping there's an easy solution I've overlooked.

Comment: hmm. maybe look into @cucumberoptions

other than that, you can also just try replicating the java file in different sub-directories.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/    http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please look for "tags" in the documentation:

https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags

For example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/tags/first.feature

Comment: Thanks Thomas.
Yes, --tags or --name cucumber options will work however I wanted to retain the ability to run a suite of tests within the folder hierarchy.
Another option I explored was altering the CucumberRunner.parallel call in TestParallel.java by setting the class argument to my chosen Java runner class. This yields the correct Cucumber report, but it seems that all tests still run. Is this the intended functionality?

Comment: @M.Darke maybe you made the mistake of using the `@RunWith` annotation, refer doc. also a suggestion, a good way to filter by folder is to do something like `@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:animals/cats", tags = "~@ignore") ` note that all features in `animals/cats` will be run